# How do I access a box in an array?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I have an indicator in which Box will be used as content in an array. These boxes indicate Buy or Sell blocks. I would now like to trigger an alert when the open or close of a candle crosses the box. I tried to read the values from the box:

```
box_bot = box.get_bottom(boxes)
box_left = box.get_left(boxes)
box_right = box.get_right(boxes)
box_top = box.get_top(boxes)
```

But I get the error message:
Cannot call 'box.get_bottom' with argument 'id'='boxes'. An argument of 'box[]' type was used but a 'series box' is expected.

Unfortunately, I don't yet really understand the principle of how to address the box and read the top or bottom line of the box in order to then implement an alert.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Test 84', overlay=true, max_bars_back=500)

from = input.int(0, minval=0, maxval=400, step=1, tooltip = "start candle, maxval=400")
loockback = input.int(20, minval=10, maxval=500, tooltip="The number of candles selected for the calculation to go back from the starting candle. Selecting the number of candles greater than 200 can cause errors in the time required for processing. minval=10, maxval=500")
resist_high_slice = input.int(11, "Resist high slice",minval=11, maxval=60, tooltip="Aim for the highest green-to-red volume ratio by setting the maximum number of slices from Highest momentum price to close[]of start candle. minval=11, maxval=60")
supp_high_slice = input.int(11, "supp high slice",minval=11, maxval=60, tooltip="Aim for the highest red-to-green volume ratio by setting the maximum number of slices from Lowest momentum price to close[]of start candle. minval=11, maxval=60")
resist_nu = input.int(1, "Resistance Number",minval=1, maxval=3, tooltip="")
supp_nu = input.int(1, "Support Number",minval=1, maxval=3, tooltip="")
var nvl = matrix.new<float>(resist_nu+supp_nu,8,0) //Best layers storage table
var nvl_s = matrix.new<string>(resist_nu+supp_nu,2,na)
var L = array.new_label(2*(resist_nu+supp_nu),na)
var boxes = array.new_box(resist_nu+supp_nu,na)
var Lines = array.new_line(5, na)
start = from
end = from + loockback
var int savedata = na
var line baseLine = na

if barstate.islast
    max_bars_back(time,500)
    matrix.fill(nvl, 0, 0, resist_nu+supp_nu, 0, 7)
    matrix.fill(nvl_s, na, 0, resist_nu+supp_nu, 0, 2)
    line.delete(baseLine)
    for j = 0 to 2*(resist_nu+supp_nu)-1
        lb = array.get(L, j)
        label.delete(lb)
    for j = 0 to 4
        lb = array.get(Lines, j)
        line.delete(lb)
    hst = 0.0
    lst = 0.0
    hstcount = 0
    lstcount = 0
    for i = start to end
        if i == from
            hst := high[i]
            hstcount := i
            lst := low[i]
            lstcount := i
        if close[i]>open[i] and ((high[i]-close[i])+(open[i]-low[i]))<(close[i]-open[i]) //Green momentum candle
            if high[i]>hst
                hst := high[i]
                hstcount := i
        if close[i]<open[i] and ((high[i]-open[i])+(close[i]-low[i]))<(open[i]-close[i]) //Red momentum candle
            if low[i]<lst
                lst := low[i]
                lstcount := i
    //array.insert(L,0,label.new(bar_index-hstcount, high[hstcount], "Highest momentum price", color = color.new(color.red,60), textalign = text.align_center,style = label.style_label_lower_right))
    //array.insert(L,0,label.new(bar_index-lstcount, low[lstcount], "Lowest momentum price", color = color.new(color.green,60), textalign = text.align_center,style = label.style_label_upper_right))
    array.insert(Lines,0,line.new(bar_index - lstcount, lst, bar_index - hstcount, hst, width=3, color=color.white))
    //CALCULATING VOLUME IN LAYERS
    for k = resist_high_slice to resist_nu
        pr = 0.0
        if close[from]>=low[hstcount]
            pr := (hst - hlc3[hstcount]) / k //layer height
        else
            pr := (hst - close[from]) / k //layer height
        for j = 0 to k-1 //Resistance
            green_vol = 0.0
            red_vol = 0.0
            green_candles = 0
            red_candles = 0
            for i = start to end //candles
                if high[i]<=(hst - (j*pr)) and low[i]>=(hst - ((j+1)*pr)) //1
                    if close[i]>open[i]
                        green_vol += volume[i]
                        green_candles += 1
                    else
                        red_vol += volume[i]
                        red_candles += 1
                if high[i]<=(hst - (j*pr)) and high[i]>(hst - ((j+1)*pr)) and low[i]<(hst - ((j+1)*pr)) //2
                    if close[i]>open[i]
                        green_vol += (math.abs(high[i]-(hst - ((j+1)*pr))) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        green_candles += 1
                    else
                        red_vol += (math.abs(high[i]-(hst - ((j+1)*pr))) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        red_candles += 1
                if high[i]>(hst - (j*pr)) and low[i]<(hst - (j*pr)) and low[i]>=(hst - ((j+1)*pr)) //3
                    if close[i]>open[i]
                        green_vol += (math.abs((hst - (j*pr))-low[i]) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        green_candles += 1
                    else
                        red_vol += (math.abs((hst - (j*pr))-low[i]) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        red_candles += 1
                if high[i]>(hst - (j*pr)) and low[i]<(hst - ((j+1)*pr)) //4
                    if close[i]>open[i]
                        green_vol += (math.abs((hst - (j*pr))-(hst - ((j+1)*pr))) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        green_candles += 1
                    else
                        red_vol += (math.abs((hst - (j*pr))-(hst - ((j+1)*pr))) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        red_candles += 1
            savedata := na
            for x = 0 to resist_nu-1
                if matrix.get(nvl, x, 0)==0 and na(savedata) == true
                    savedata := x
                if matrix.get(nvl, x, 0)!=0 and (hst - (j*pr))>=matrix.get(nvl, x, 1)
                    savedata := resist_nu
                if matrix.get(nvl, x, 0)!=0 and na(savedata) == true and (hst - (j*pr))<matrix.get(nvl, x, 1)
                    if green_vol>0 and red_vol==0
                        if k<matrix.get(nvl, x, 0)
                            savedata := x
                    if green_vol>0 and red_vol>0 and na(savedata) == true
                        if ((green_vol/red_vol)>(matrix.get(nvl, x, 3)/matrix.get(nvl, x, 4))) and green_candles>=matrix.get(nvl, x, 6) and red_candles<=matrix.get(nvl, x, 7)
                            savedata := x
                        if (green_vol/red_vol)==(matrix.get(nvl, x, 3)/matrix.get(nvl, x, 4)) and pr>matrix.get(nvl, x, 5) and na(savedata) == true
                            savedata := x
            if na(savedata) == false and savedata<resist_nu
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 0, k)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 1, (hst - ((j+1)*pr))) //The bottom border of the layer
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 2, (hst - (j*pr))) //The top border of the layer
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 3, green_vol)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 4, red_vol)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 5, pr)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 6, green_candles)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 7, red_candles)
    for k = supp_high_slice to supp_nu
        pr = 0.0
        if close[from]<=high[lstcount]
            pr := (hlc3[lstcount] - lst) / k
        else
            pr := (close[from] - lst) / k
        for j = 0 to k-1 //Resistance
            green_vol = 0.0
            red_vol = 0.0
            green_candles = 0
            red_candles = 0
            for i = start to end //candles
                if high[i]<=(lst + ((j+1)*pr)) and low[i]>=(lst + (j*pr)) //1
                    if close[i]>open[i]
                        green_vol += volume[i]
                        green_candles += 1
                    else
                        red_vol += volume[i]
                        red_candles += 1
                if high[i]<=(lst + ((j+1)*pr)) and high[i]>(lst + (j*pr)) and low[i]<(lst + (j*pr)) //2
                    if close[i]>open[i]
                        green_vol += (math.abs(high[i]-(lst + (j*pr))) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        green_candles += 1
                    else
                        red_vol += (math.abs(high[i]-(lst + (j*pr))) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        red_candles += 1
                if high[i]>(lst + ((j+1)*pr)) and low[i]<(lst + ((j+1)*pr)) and low[i]>=(lst + (j*pr)) //3
                    if close[i]>open[i]
                        green_vol += (math.abs((lst + ((j+1)*pr))-low[i]) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        green_candles += 1
                    else
                        red_vol += (math.abs((lst + ((j+1)*pr))-low[i]) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        red_candles += 1
                if high[i]>(lst + ((j+1)*pr)) and low[i]<(lst + (j*pr)) //4
                    if close[i]>open[i]
                        green_vol += (math.abs((lst + ((j+1)*pr))-(lst + (j*pr))) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        green_candles += 1
                    else
                        red_vol += (math.abs((lst + ((j+1)*pr))-(lst + (j*pr))) / math.abs(high[i]-low[i]))*volume[i]
                        red_candles += 1
            savedata := na
            for x = resist_nu to (resist_nu+supp_nu)-1
                if matrix.get(nvl, x, 0)==0 and na(savedata) == true
                    savedata := x
                if matrix.get(nvl, x, 0)!=0 and (lst + (j*pr))<=matrix.get(nvl, x, 2)
                    savedata := resist_nu+supp_nu
                if matrix.get(nvl, x, 0)!=0 and na(savedata) == true and (lst + (j*pr))>matrix.get(nvl, x, 2)
                    if red_vol>0 and green_vol==0
                        if k<matrix.get(nvl, x, 0)
                            savedata := x
                    if red_vol>0 and green_vol>0 and na(savedata) == true
                        if (red_vol/green_vol)>(matrix.get(nvl, x, 4)/matrix.get(nvl, x, 3)) and green_candles<=matrix.get(nvl, x, 6) and red_candles>=matrix.get(nvl, x, 7)
                            savedata := x
                        if (red_vol/green_vol)==(matrix.get(nvl, x, 4)/matrix.get(nvl, x, 3)) and pr>matrix.get(nvl, x, 5) and na(savedata) == true
                            savedata := x
            if na(savedata) == false and savedata<resist_nu+supp_nu
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 0, k)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 1, (lst + (j*pr))) //The bottom border of the layer
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 2, (lst + ((j+1)*pr))) //The top border of the layer
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 3, green_vol)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 4, red_vol)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 5, pr)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 6, green_candles)
                matrix.set(nvl, savedata, 7, red_candles)
if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to (resist_nu+supp_nu) - 1
        lb = array.get(boxes, i)
        box.delete(lb)
    //FORMATING VOLUMES
    for j = 0 to (resist_nu+supp_nu) - 1
        string formatPrecision = "#" + "0.000000"
        for i = 3 to 4 //The the amount of green and red volumes are stored in indexes 3 and 4 of the table, respectively.
            float gvol_digitsAmt = math.log10(math.abs(matrix.get(nvl,j,i)))
            string sgvd = if gvol_digitsAmt > 12
                str.tostring(matrix.get(nvl,j,i) / 1e12, formatPrecision + " T")
            else if gvol_digitsAmt > 9
                str.tostring(matrix.get(nvl,j,i) / 1e9, formatPrecision + " B")
            else if gvol_digitsAmt > 6
                str.tostring(matrix.get(nvl,j,i) / 1e6, formatPrecision + " M")
            else if gvol_digitsAmt > 3
                str.tostring(matrix.get(nvl,j,i) / 1e3, formatPrecision + " K")
            else
                str.tostring(matrix.get(nvl,j,i), "#" + formatPrecision)
            matrix.set(nvl_s, j, i-3, sgvd)
        //lable assembly
        string strLL = na
        if j < resist_nu
            strLL := str.format("cutting = {0,number,#} Layers",matrix.get(nvl,j,0))
            strLL := strLL + str.format("\nlayer height = {0,number,#.########}",matrix.get(nvl,j,5))
            strLL := strLL + str.format("\n{0,number,#.#########}",matrix.get(nvl,j,1))
            strLL := strLL + str.format(" >>> {0,number,#.########}",matrix.get(nvl,j,2))
            strLL := strLL +"\ngreen_vol = "+str.tostring(matrix.get(nvl_s,j,0))
            strLL := strLL +"\nred_vol = "+str.tostring(matrix.get(nvl_s,j,1))
            if matrix.get(nvl,j,4)>0
                strLL := strLL +"\n(green_vol / red_vol) = "+str.tostring((matrix.get(nvl,j,3)/matrix.get(nvl,j,4)))
            else if matrix.get(nvl,j,4)==0
                strLL := strLL + "\n(green_vol / red_vol) = Unlimited"
            if j == 0
                //array.insert(L,0,label.new(bar_index-from, matrix.get(nvl,j,2), strLL, textalign = text.align_center,style = label.style_label_lower_left,color =color.new(color.red,80)))
                array.insert(boxes,0,box.new(bar_index-from-loockback, matrix.get(nvl,j,2), bar_index-from, matrix.get(nvl,j,1),bgcolor=color.new(color.red,20), border_color=color.new(color.red,100),border_width = 6))
            else
                array.insert(boxes,0,box.new(bar_index-from-loockback, matrix.get(nvl,j,2), bar_index-from, matrix.get(nvl,j,1),bgcolor=color.new(color.red,20), border_color=color.new(color.red,100),border_width = 6))
        if j >= resist_nu
            strLL := str.format("cutting = {0,number,#} Layers",matrix.get(nvl,j,0))
            strLL := strLL + str.format("\nlayer height = {0,number,#.########}",matrix.get(nvl,j,5))
            strLL := strLL + str.format("\n{0,number,#.#########}",matrix.get(nvl,j,1))
            strLL := strLL + str.format(" >>> {0,number,#.########}",matrix.get(nvl,j,2))
            strLL := strLL +"\ngreen_vol = "+str.tostring(matrix.get(nvl_s,j,0))
            strLL := strLL +"\nred_vol = "+str.tostring(matrix.get(nvl_s,j,1))
            if matrix.get(nvl,j,3)>0
                strLL := strLL +"\n(red_vol / green_vol) = "+str.tostring((matrix.get(nvl,j,4)/matrix.get(nvl,j,3)))
            else if matrix.get(nvl,j,3)==0
                strLL := strLL + "\n(red_vol / green_vol) = Unlimited"
            if j == resist_nu
                //array.insert(L,0,label.new(bar_index-from, matrix.get(nvl,j,1), strLL, textalign = text.align_center,style = label.style_label_upper_left,color =color.new(color.green,80)))
                array.insert(boxes,0,box.new(bar_index-from-loockback, matrix.get(nvl,j,2), bar_index-from, matrix.get(nvl,j,1),bgcolor=color.new(color.green,20), border_color=color.new(color.green,100),border_width = 6))
            else
                array.insert(boxes,0,box.new(bar_index-from-loockback, matrix.get(nvl,j,2), bar_index-from, matrix.get(nvl,j,1),bgcolor=color.new(color.green,20), border_color=color.new(color.green,100),border_width = 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

your example isn't inside your script so I will give you an example too.
Normally you will need an *ID* to access the array and the *INDEX* to access its value.

The following examples uses four different methods to access the values of objects inside an array...

```
box_bot = boxes.last().get_bottom()   // no id nor index needed cause of array.last() or array.first(), and method *.get_*() or *.set_*()

my_box  = array.get(boxes, array.size(boxes) - 1)  // here you need the id and the index to access its value
box_left = my_box.get_left()

box_right = array.get(boxes, array.size(boxes) - 1).get_right()    // this needs both too

the_same_box = array.last(boxes)  // only the id is needed
box_top = the_same_box.get_top()
```

[HERE](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html) is the howto for arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the options work. Are there other possibilities. In addition, a distinction should be made between the short and long boxes.

Comment: @Max who did write the script?